# Download M3u8 but it's a jpg file not a ts

Tags: web-crawler, jpeg, m3u8

I found that there are some videos on the site.

I got the M3U8 file.

But it's full of jpgs.

How do I turn this into a video file?

#### m3u8

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXTINF:4.254133,
https://ali2.a.yximgs.com/udata/music/music_fa047f4ba4bb401a94cd631a0ca97d340.jpg
#EXTINF:3.003011,
https://js2.a.yximgs.com/udata/music/music_1b18b287db824280ae27b696ef22ae570.jpg
#EXTINF:2.669344,
https://js2.a.yximgs.com/udata/music/music_c1f1495ee027461f99047a8db0d3b5050.jpg
...
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @JackFleeting I use Chinese, is this related to the language?

Comment: No :) I meant programming language....

Comment: @JackFleeting I'm so sorry, I use Python

Comment: Ok, now that we got that out of way: an M3U8 file is a text file, it doesn't have any JPGs or videos - only links to them. So what is it exactly you want to do?

Comment: @JackFleeting But M3U8 is not Ts but JPG, why can this M3U8 be turned into a video on the website? And there is sound.

Comment: Or is this M3U8 actually a trick? my ideal is to download videos.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "trick", but the snippet in your question doesn't contain any video or audio links, just image links.

Comment: I just downloaded the first jpg and opened it with vim, and found the message of `H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec`, I guess the jpg is the encrypted video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After research, read jpg and delete the first bytes, it will be mp4 image.

This jpg is just misleading.

Comment: Could you tell me what tool you finally used to download the misleading m3u8 file? I have a similar file which states .jpg as the extension in m3u8 but in reality they are .ts files...

Comment: @Sujal Just use the general requests to download, `with open` to read the file, delete the first few bytes of the file, and you can use it.

Comment: At that time, after downloading the file, I read the file and performed `save(file[1:])` or `save(file[??:])` similar to this operation.

Comment: Seems like your files were a bit different than mine, mine were just `.ts` files renamed to `.jpg`. I was trying to download it with ffmpeg and it kept showing corrupted packet but then I noticed that it was just a warning and ffmpeg was automatically able to decipher those `.jpg` files as `.ts`. But thanks for your reply!